# Three different definitions of a function, no linker error; how can that be?

Tags: c++

I have something which looks very impossible to me. I have three files which each seem to contain the exact same function declaration, albeit with a different definition.

`inst_dp_vec2.cc`:

```
void loadSOAFVec(InstVector &ivector,
                 const FVec &ret,
                 const Address *a,
                 int soanum,
                 int soalen,
                 string mask) {
    if (soalen == 2) {
        ivector.push_back(new LoadFVec(ret, a, string("")));
    } else {
        printf("SOALEN = %d not supported at %s:%d\n", soalen, __FILE__,
               __LINE__);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

`inst_dp_vec4.cc`

```
void loadSOAFVec(InstVector &ivector,
                 const FVec &ret,
                 const Address *a,
                 int soanum,
                 int soalen,
                 string mask) {
    if (soalen == 4) {
        ivector.push_back(new LoadFVec(ret, a, string("")));
    } else if (soalen == 2) {
        ivector.push_back(new LoadHalfFVec(ret, a, soanum));
    } else {
        UNSUPPORTED_SOALEN(soalen);
    }
}
```

`inst_dp_vec8.cc`

```
void loadSOAFVec(InstVector &ivector,
                 const FVec &ret,
                 const Address *a,
                 int soanum,
                 int soalen,
                 string mask) {
    int mskbits = (((1 << soalen) - 1) << (soanum * soalen));
    stringstream mk;
    mk << "0x" << hex << mskbits;
    string localmask = mk.str();
    ivector.push_back(new LoadUnpackFVec(ret, a, localmask));
}
```

The linker command as executed from the Makefile (generated by GNU Autotools)
seems to include all three compiled files:

```
g++ -O3 -g -DNO_HW_MASKING -DUSE_LDUNPK -DUSE_PKST -DUSE_PACKED_GAUGES
-DUSE_PACKED_CLOVER -DNO_GPREF_L1 -DNO_GPREF_L2 -DENABLE_STREAMING_STORES
-DSERIAL_SPIN -DSOALEN=8 -DVECLEN=4 -DPRECISION=2 codegen.o data_types.o
dslash.o dslash_common.o inst_dp_vec8.o inst_sp_vec16.o inst_dp_vec4.o
inst_sp_vec8.o inst_sp_vec4.o inst_dp_vec2.o inst_scalar.o -o codegen
```

From my knowledge of the *one definition rule*, this should give a linker
error. Even more peculiar is that the version from `inst_dp_vec8.o` is not the
one used, but the one from `inst_dp_vec4.cc`, although it appears first in the
linker command line. I changed the code such that `UNSUPPORTED_SOALEN` throws
an exception and with GDB I found that `soalen = 8` is active. From what I know
about the software, `soalen = 8` only works with `veclen ≥ 8` such that only
the `inst_dp_vec8.cc` could contain the right definition.

My question: How can this possible link to a program that can be executed and
only fails because of the explicit exception raised with `UNSUPPORTED_SOALEN`?

Comment: Could you isolate it into a [mcve]?

Comment: There's a zillion reasons why this can happen (about as many as lines of code we don't get to see, in particular lines of code that say something like `#define  FVec vec2` (hint, look at the filenames)). That's why you are asked to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: Since they're each a separate source file, each one gets compiled into it's own object file - there is no naming collision.

Comment: @GovindParmar nope.

Comment: @GovindParmar: There is no naming collision at the compilation level. There is one, however, at the *linking* level.

Comment: @RustyX: I will work on that. It might as well happen I understand the problem while preparing it. I first wanted to know whether I have lost my sanity or whether something really odd is going on.

Comment: Look carefully at the end of each of the three files. Do you see a big bold `#endif` in each of them? If you do, find the corresponding `#if`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because no diagnostic is required when the multiple definitions occur in multiple translation units.

From [basic.def.odr]:

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.

and later

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement (6.4.1); no diagnostic required.

So you get an error if they are multiple definitions within on source module, but don't have to get them if they're in different ones.

Comment: You won't be able to *link* such an application though. Which is what the question is about.

Comment: It is true that a linker is never *required by the standard* to detect odr violations, but most linkers usually do detect them. I'm curious to know why that isn't the case here. Probably impossible to tell without a [mcve] from OP though. My guess is that there isn't an odr violation in the first place.

Comment: Ouch, so basically this is undefined behavior then and it is undefined which of the three functions ends up in the program? Then it would be job of the build system to just link one file into the final executable?

Comment: No, you're probably missing some conditional compilation.

Comment: @RustyX It's up to the linker how to handle the situation.  It could issue a warning, an error, or just pick one and go with it.  Just picking one is the easiest way to handle multiple definitions of inline defined functions when the optimization settings have completely disabled inlining.

Comment: By standard, every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function.  Thus it gets to freely assume that the first one it sees is the only one, and stop looking.  Or when building a lookup table, blindly overwrite any existing entry with the most recently found as there can only be one in a valid program anyway.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The linker in question is not a hypothetical linker that can do this or that depending on phases of the moon. It is one well known well documented linker. Be rest assured it does issue a very loud error when there is more than one definition of a function.